# Organizing membership information

Tags: vba, excel

I am relatively new to coding, and have very little experience. With help from Google and research I have been able to successfully write a code that cuts the workload in a specific task significantly for me. I have a huge list of membership information from an organization that changes weekly, and I need to pull data from a master list, and distribute it to their correct worksheet in Excel.

However, I am convinced that this is really sloppy code, and someone else could certainly have written something better.

Me being curious though, my question is: Is there any advantages to optimizing a code like mine, when it works exactly as I want it to?

```
Sub Slett_all_data()
' Sletter all data i listene før ny oppdatering

With Sheets("OK")
    .Rows(3 & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
End With
With Sheets("Mangler ID")
    .Rows(3 & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
End With
With Sheets("Mangler betaling")
    .Rows(3 & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
End With
With Sheets("Mangler prøve")
    .Rows(3 & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
End With
With Sheets("Mangler alt")
    .Rows(3 & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
End With
End Sub

Sub Sorter_all_data()
' Henter ut data fra "Status" og sorterer ut på de ulike arkene

Dim c As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim l As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet
Dim Target2 As Worksheet
Dim Target3 As Worksheet
Dim Target4 As Worksheet
Dim Target5 As Worksheet

Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Status")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OK")
Set Target2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Mangler ID")
Set Target3 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Mangler betaling")
Set Target4 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Mangler prøve")
Set Target5 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Mangler alt")

j = 2
k = 2
l = 2
m = 2
n = 2

'Godkjente
For Each c In Source.Range("F1:F300")
    If c = "Ja" And c.Offset(0, 3) = "Ja" And c.Offset(0, 4) = "Ja" Then
       Source.Rows(c.Row).Cut Target.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1

'Mangler ID
    ElseIf c = "Ja" And c.Offset(0, 3) = "Nei" And c.Offset(0, 4) = "Ja" Then
       Source.Rows(c.Row).Cut Target2.Rows(k)
       k = k + 1

'Mangler alt
    ElseIf c = "Nei" And c.Offset(0, 3) = "Nei" And c.Offset(0, 4) = "Nei" Then
       Source.Rows(c.Row).Cut Target5.Rows(n)
       n = n + 1

'Mangler betaling
    ElseIf c.Offset(0, 4) = "Nei" Then
       Source.Rows(c.Row).Cut Target3.Rows(l)
       l = l + 1

'Mangler prøve
    ElseIf c = "Nei" Then
       Source.Rows(c.Row).Cut Target4.Rows(m)
       m = m + 1
    End If
Next c

End Sub

Sub TabellOK()
'Rejusterer tabellstørrelse etter ny datamengde

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("OK")
Set StartCell = sht.Range("A1")

'Refresh UsedRange
  Worksheets("OK").UsedRange

'Find Last Row and Column
  LastRow = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
  LastColumn = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

'Select Range
sht.Select
  sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select

'Update table
  sht.ListObjects("OK").Resize Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))

End Sub

Sub TabellID()
'Rejusterer tabellstørrelse etter ny datamengde

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Mangler ID")
Set StartCell = sht.Range("A1")

    Worksheets("Mangler ID").UsedRange
    LastRow = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    LastColumn = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    sht.Select
    sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select
    sht.ListObjects("ID").Resize Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))


End Sub

Sub TabellBetaling()
'Rejusterer tabellstørrelse etter ny datamengde

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Mangler betaling")
Set StartCell = sht.Range("A1")

    Worksheets("Mangler betaling").UsedRange
    LastRow = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    LastColumn = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    sht.Select
    sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select
    sht.ListObjects("Betaling").Resize Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))

End Sub

Sub Tabellprøve()
'Rejusterer tabellstørrelse etter ny datamengde

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Mangler prøve")
Set StartCell = sht.Range("A1")

    Worksheets("Mangler prøve").UsedRange
    LastRow = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    LastColumn = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    sht.Select
    sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select
    sht.ListObjects("Prøve").Resize Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))

End Sub

Sub Tabellalt()
'Rejusterer tabellstørrelse etter ny datamengde

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Mangler alt")
Set StartCell = sht.Range("A1")

    Worksheets("Mangler alt").UsedRange
    LastRow = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    LastColumn = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
    sht.Select
    sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select
    sht.ListObjects("Alt").Resize Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))

End Sub

Sub Gjennomfør()
'Kjører alle makroer i gitt rekkefølge

Call Slett_all_data     'Sletter alle data
Call Sorter_all_data    'Sorterer alle data
Call TabellOK           'Rejusterer tabellstørrelse etter ny datamengde
Call TabellID           'Rejusterer tabellstørrelse etter ny datamengde
Call TabellBetaling     'Rejusterer tabellstørrelse etter ny datamengde
Call Tabellprøve        'Rejusterer tabellstørrelse etter ny datamengde
Call Tabellalt          'Rejusterer tabellstørrelse etter ny datamengde

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: The point of optimizing would be to decrease chances for an error to happen, make it easier to maintain your code (fixes and alterations), improve speed, etc. While there are good practices in coding that are worth adhering to, it should still be a matter of costs/benefits. If you are the one to use the code, the errors are not a big risk, changes will be rare - then the main thing is that it works. If you will continue to code in future it is a good idea to learn good practices from the start as it will spare you time and effort.

Comment: ^^ what @VictorK said. I'll add, that the only time it doesn't matter, is when you're writing throw-away code you're going to run once and then never going to look at ever again. Any other code *deserves* to be written in a way that if the next maintainer is a violent psychopath that knows where you live, you've nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

### Constant Expressions

Adding Constant expressions to you code will make it easier to read, write, and maintain your code.  If your were to change the names of any Worksheet or Table, updating your code would be a simple matter of changing the value of the relevant Constant.  They will also allow you to Intellisense, which by itself is a huge advantage.

### Repeated Code

Repeated code can generally be extracted into it's own separate method.  Any variables that are changed between repeated block of code can be passed into the new subroutine as parameters.

### Variable Naming

Constants should be written in all caps and have a meaningful name.  I remove **Mangler** from the variable names and used `WS_` to indicate a Worksheet name and TBL_ to indicate a Table name.

The variable `c as Range` was replaced with `cell as Range` because a range is an Object and Objects should be described by a Noun.  I use 1 letter names for counters (e.g. i, j, x, y or i1, i2).

### Variable Declarations

Combine variable declarations of the same type alphabetically.  It is much easier to read, debug, and modify code when you do not have to scroll.

```
Dim c As Range
Dim j As Integer, k As Integer, l As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet, Target As Worksheet, Target2 As Worksheet, Target3 As Worksheet, Target4 As Worksheet, Target5 As Worksheet
```

### Comments

Large code blocks that perform many tasks should be heavily commented. In most cases, however, these large code blocks should broken up into several subroutines that perform 1 or 2 simple tasks.  After extracting the tasks, you will find that the using descriptive names for the smaller subroutines is far more readable than heavy commenting.  That being said, I think that you did a pretty good job of commenting.  I do not comment nearly enough.

### Refactored Code

```
Option Explicit
Public Const WS_OK As String = "OK"
Public Const WS_ID As String = "Mangler ID"
Public Const WS_BETALING As String = "Mangler betaling"
Public Const WS_PRØVE As String = "Mangler prøve"
Public Const WS_ALT As String = "Mangler alt"
Public Const WS_STATUS As String = "Status"

Public Const TBL_OK As String = "OK"
Public Const TBL_ID As String = "ID"
Public Const TBL_BETALING As String = "Betaling"
Public Const TBL_PRØVE As String = "Prøve"
Public Const TBL_ALT As String = "Alt"
'Public Const TBL_STATUS As String = "Status"

Sub Gjennomfør()
'Kjører alle makroer i gitt rekkefølge
    Slett_all_data
    Sorter_all_data
    ResizeTable WS_OK, TBL_OK
    ResizeTable WS_ID, TBL_ID
    ResizeTable WS_BETALING, TBL_BETALING
    ResizeTable WS_PRØVE, TBL_PRØVE
    ResizeTable WS_ALT, TBL_ALT
    MsgBox "Gjennomfør Finished", vbInformation, "Success"
End Sub

Private Sub ResizeTable(WorkSheetName As String, TableName As String)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(WorkSheetName)
        .ListObjects(TableName).Resize .Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Slett_all_data()
' Sletter all data i listene før ny oppdatering
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array(WS_OK, WS_ID, WS_BETALING, WS_PRØVE, WS_ALT))
        With ws
            .Rows(3 & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
        End With
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Sorter_all_data()
' Henter ut data fra "Status" og sorterer ut på de ulike arkene
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim WorkSheetName As String
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(WS_STATUS)
        For Each cell In .Range("F1:F300")            'Dynamic range alternative .Range("F1", "F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If cell = "Ja" And cell.Offset(0, 3) = "Ja" And cell.Offset(0, 4) = "Ja" Then
                TransferRow cell, WS_OK
            ElseIf cell = "Ja" And cell.Offset(0, 3) = "Nei" And cell.Offset(0, 4) = "Ja" Then
                TransferRow cell, WS_ID
            ElseIf cell = "Nei" And cell.Offset(0, 3) = "Nei" And cell.Offset(0, 4) = "Nei" Then
                TransferRow cell, WS_ALT
            ElseIf cell.Offset(0, 4) = "Nei" Then
                TransferRow cell, WS_BETALING
            ElseIf cell = "Nei" Then
                TransferRow cell, WS_PRØVE
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub TransferRow(cell As Range, WorkSheetName As String)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(WorkSheetName)
        cell.EntireRow.Cut .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Obvious picks:

- Indentation:
  The code is not indented for one level inside Subs and Functions. This makes it harder to skim the code and notice where Subs / Functions begin and end.
- Call-Statement:
  The `Call`-Statement is obsolete. Drop it :)
- Naming_conVention:
  The naming is inconsistent between `Slett_all_data` and `Tabellprøve` and `TabellBetaling`. Choose one casing convention (and language) and stick to it: `SlettData`
- Overcommenting:
  If one chooses speaking names, comments like in `Gjennomfør` become redundant. Don't make comments say what the code says. Make them explain **why** the code does what it does.
- Naming itself:
  It's generally bad form to "number" variables. Instead of `Target`, `Target2`, ... it'd be easier to read later if the targets were named after what they *mean* not what they are. `ManglerId`, `ManglerBetaling`, `ManglerPrøve` and `ManglerAlt` are much more speaking names that make it easier to reason about the code.

Bonus Round :)

- Good job on extracting subs. The next step is to extract "constants" across subs onto the module level. Stuff like the different sheets you access can be in the global scope:

  ```
  Private ManglerId As Worksheet = Worksheets("Mangler ID")
  Private ManglerBetaling As Worksheet = Worksheets("Mangler Betaling")
  ' ...
  ```
- On a similar note: Good job on accessing `Worksheets` instead of `Sheets`

Now if I could speak Norwegian (did google translate guess right?) I could possibly even say something about your business logic, but since I can't you'll have to content yourself with this little superfluous review from my side :)

Comment: `Private Const ManglerId As Worksheet = Worksheets("Mangler ID")` will not work in the VBA.

Comment: @ThomasInzina right you are. I tend to forget that not everything in VBA that looks like a functioncall can be shoehorned into a compile-time constant ...

Comment: I wish that we could instantiate variable like in VBA like it is done in other languages.